# How to avoid the numerous calls to my DB? (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

With the following code I get all the pages I admin on Facebook using FQL. I do not print them though.

```
$PageNames = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q' => 
        'SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (
               SELECT page_id FROM page_admin  WHERE  uid=me() )'));
```

Previously, I have added in my DB the *page_id* of some of my pages. My goal is to show the pages that I have not added to my DB yet. It is working correctly and the code is below.

```
  foreach($PageNames['data'] as $PageName) {
    $investigate_id = mysql_query("SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE page_id='"
                                  .$PageName['page_id']."' LIMIT 1 ");

      if(mysql_num_rows($investigate_id) == 0) {
        echo $PageName['page_id'].$PageName['name'];
      }

  }
```

My problem/question is if somehow I can avoid the numerous DB calls because it makes the query for every page I admin. How can I achieve this?

Comment: put the ids together and use WHERE page_id IN(.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may collect the IDs from results you got with FQL and then query DB for rows that exists in results to filter those present in DB from results...

```
$fql = <<<FQL
SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (
  SELECT page_id FROM page_admin  WHERE uid = me()
)
FQL;

// Get results from API
$pages = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q' => $fql));

// Collect pages for later usage by ID
$pagesByIds = array();
foreach($pages['data'] as $page){
    $pagesByIds[$page['page_id']] = $page;
}

// Query DB for all pages that exists in results
$pagesIds = implode(',', array_keys($pageByIds));
$res = mysql_query("SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE page_id IN ({$pageIds})");

while($pageRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $pageId = $pageRow['page_id'];

  // Remove pages that present in API results and DB
  if (isset($pagesById[$pageId])) unset($pagesById[$pageId]); ;
}

// Display details for pages not existing in DB
foreach ($pagesByIds as $page){
  echo "ID: {$page['page_id']}, Name: {$page['name']} \n"
}
```

Comment: @Kaoukkos, if the issue was only the name it shoul be boxed now

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used your code to build my solution with some changes. It really helped me.

Comment: I have tested your method but it does not "hide" the pages found in DB. Instead, it shows all the pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$IDs = array();
foreach($PageNames['data'] as $PageName){
    $IDs[] = $PageName['page_id'];
}

$investigate_id = mysql_query('SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE page_id IN (\''.implode('\', \'', $IDs)).' LIMIT 1 ');
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($investigate_id)){
    // iff
}
?>
```

Using WHERE col IN will make one query will all ID so

WHERE page_id IN (1,3,45,6,7,6,7,5,2,1,5,76) and it will do it in query, just make the loop after over the results and do whatever you want !

Comment: There is an error but I can not figure it out. It's on the query

Comment: @David forgot the closing bracket, IN (\''.implode('\', \'', $IDs)).'\')  LIMIT 1 '